# Doxygen \sa links within external namespaces

Tags: documentation, doxygen

I have two c# class files, both in different namespaces. I was wondering how to put a Doxygen \sa 'See Also:' link within my comments when the method I am trying to reference exists in a different namespace.

My example is below:

File1.cs

```
namespace namespace1
{
    public partial class class1
    {        
        /*! \brief My Description for PublicFunction
         *  \sa namespace2.class2.PublicFunctionInNamespace2
         */
        public void PublicFunction()
        {
            // Code Here...
        }
    }
}
```

File2.cs

```
namespace namespace2
{
    public partial class class2
    {
        /*! \brief My Description for PublicFunctionInNamespace2
         */
        public void PublicFunctionInNamespace2()
        {
            // Code Here...
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I figured it out.

Make sure when your referencing the file that you include NamespaceName.ClassName.MethodName.

Ex: namespace2.class2.PublicFunctionInNamespace2 as edited in the above post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Make sure when your referencing the file that you include NamespaceName.ClassName.MethodName.

Ex: namespace2.class2.PublicFunctionInNamespace2 as edited in the above post.